# Create Site in Alfresco using the Apache Chemistry

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

Greetings to the community! I am using alfresco Community Edition 6.0.0 with the `Apache Chemistry API`. I have successfully managed so far to create/fetch content from the alfresco repository through it (Folder and Document files).

Now what I would like to do is use the Apache Chemistry API to **create an alfresco site** (like I would do using the `alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/sites` POST method in the Alfresco REST API).

Is that feasible?? What I have done following the way I already created folders in the repository is:

```
Folder folder = retrieveSitesFolder(); // this returns the folder object using the node id of the "Sites" node
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "F:st:site"); //this is recognized fine
props.put("st:siteVisibility", "PUBLIC");
props.put("st:sitePreset", "something");
props.put("cmis:name", "something"); 
Folder subFolder = folder.createFolder(props);
```

I am following the site model from here concerning the properties I add 
https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2a/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/siteModel.xml

Unfortunately, when I run this piece of code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: 10290059 Site something does not exist.
```

which seems to me very strange as what I expect my code to do is create that site not search for it in anyway.

What makes this more strange is when I created a site with name "something" via the REST API and re-run the code, the code run successfully, but I did not get any extra site in the `alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/sites` endpoint of the REST API.

Could anyone shed some light on this please? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't create a fully-functional site in Alfresco just by creating the site root node. You need to use the Share APIs to do that

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks for your reply, will take that into consideration :)

Comment: Since Alfresco 5.2 its actually possible to create a site (with default surf-config.xml:s) without using Share API:s. Have a look at the API-Explorer.
https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/sites/createSite

Comment: Hi @billerby , thanks for your comment, actually I am already using the REST api you mention as a way to create sites in the alfresco repository as you can see in my question, I was just wondering whether it is possible to create an alfresco site using the apache chemistry API, which from my so-far research seems to be partly feasible, but as Gagravarr already mentoned it will not be fully functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gagravarr says the API hasn't supported creating functional sites until, as Billerby pointed out, the REST API made some improvements.

Apache Chemistry has no idea what a site is, but, as you've discovered, an st:site is just a child type of cm:folder.

Despite that this is most likely not going to work via CMIS, I wanted to point out that you are using "something" for site preset. That is not going to work unless you've defined a new site preset called "something".

By default, there is a single out-of-the-box site preset called "site-dashboard" which is the ID for the "Collaboration Site" preset.

You might change your st:sitePreset to "site-dashboard" and see if you get any further.

Comment: I see, will check that in the direction you gave me, thanks :)